# Add new field to existing index in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, laravel-5

Ok I've created an elastic search index called users that looks like this:

```
$response = $client->index([
        'index' => 'users',
        'type' => 'user',
        'id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'body' => [
            'username' => Auth::user()->username,
            'name' => Auth::user()->name,
            'city' => Auth::user()->getCity(),
        ],

    ]);
```

I already indexed some data. I want to add a new field called 'location' to this index so that it will now be:

```
$response = $client->index([
        'index' => 'users',
        'type' => 'user',
        'id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'body' => [
            'username' => Auth::user()->username,
            'name' => Auth::user()->name,
            'city' => Auth::user()->getCity(),
            'location' => [$origin],
        ],

    ]);
```

my question is how do I add that field to the already existing data. I already have users , but without the location field. I need to add that field to the old users data so that when a user updates their info, They don't get any shard missing errors

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"document_missing_exception","reason":"[user][130]: document missing","shard":"0","index":"users"}],"type":"document_missing_exception","reason":"[user][130]: document missing","shard":"0","index":"users"},"status":404}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are seeing shards missing errors for something like this.  With Elasticsearch, mappings are dynamic by default (see [Dynamic Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-mapping.html)). This means you should be able to hit the index API as you are already doing to add new location information to existing and to new user documents and be able to search this information.

The downside to this is that you may have indexed a document where location information was assigned a certain type in the mapping and subsequent documents have location information that do not match this type (see [Field datatypes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html)). Perhaps, you might want to look into having a great control over the Elasticsearch mappings to avoid running into issues like that or maybe the issue is something else entirely.

EDIT: based on more details provided in the question recently regarding the `document_missing_exception`, this is not as relevant.

Comment: my issue is when i created the index i created it without 'location' => [$origin],, now I want to add that to my index. When i update the index with users info that signed up prior to me adding 'location' => [$origin],  I get errors trying to update{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"document_missing_exception","reason":"[user][130]: document missing","shard":"0","index":"users"}],"type":"document_missing_exception","reason":"[user][130]: document missing","shard":"0","index":"users"},"status":404}

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_updating_documents.html)

If that's a new index - the update will fail.

In order to avoid that - use upsert.

Comment: I know how to update the document, but I'm having trouble updating users that signed ip before i added 'location' => [$origin], to the index. New users I can update fine. Its users that where signed up before i added to the index I'm having trouble with

Comment: That's your misunderstanding. Update is an option of existing value in order you want to add fields (Exactly what you want to achieve), The problem with update is when the id is not found, thus you have to use Upsert (Insert when the id is not found).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your field to be populated with already indexed data, you should create a new index with desired mapping and reindex all your data. A good example is shown at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSd1aV3iVhM&list=PL_mJOmq4zsHbcdoeAwNWuhEWwDARMMBta&index=23